# Calculation of number of days considering 30 day month in C#

Tags: c#, .net, date, calendar

I'm trying to write a program which will calculate the bill amount for every month. Considering [**30/360**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention#30.2F360_Bond_Basis30/360) model. i.e The amount used for invoicing is based on a 30 day month, regardless of whether the month has 28, 30 or 31 days. I'm calculating the number of days between start date(date when a member enrolled) to end date(Date when the member disenrolled). The cost per day is $25 Here is a small table for eg:

**Dates are in (MM/DD).

> **Start Date | End Date | No. of Days | Total Amount**
>
> 05/01  |  05/31  |  30  | ($25/30)*30=25
>
> 05/10  |  05/31  |  22  | ($25/30)*22=18.33
>
> **05/10  |  06/10  |  22  | ($25/30)*22=18.33**
>
> 05/01 | 05/12 | 12    | ($25/30)*12=10
>
> 05/06 |  05/15 |  10  |  ($25/30)*10=8.33
>
> Expected result for Row 3 = ($25/30)*22=18.33
>
> Current Result = ($25/30)*31=25.83

With the code below, I'm able to get the result as expected, except for the highlighted case. How do I place a restriction to make the calculation until the end of the month? I mean if the start date is 05/10 and end date is 06/10, calculate until 05/31 based on the number of days(22).

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var start = new DateTime(2016, 05, 10);
        var finish = new DateTime(2016, 05, 28);

        var date1 = start.Day == 31 ? 30 : start.Day;
        var date2 = finish.Day == 31 && (start.Day == 30 || start.Day == 31) ? 30 : finish.Day;

        var actualDaysDiff = (finish - start).TotalDays;
        int newDaysDiff = ((360 * (finish.Year - start.Year)) + (30 * (finish.Month - start.Month)) + (date2 - date1))+1; 

        Console.WriteLine("The number of days are "+ newDaysDiff);

        float invoiceAmount = 0;
        invoiceAmount = (float)(25.0/30)*newDaysDiff;

        Console.WriteLine("Total Invoice for this month : "+ invoiceAmount);

    }
```

Eg: I don't want to calculate the number of days between start date and end date. I want to calculate the total cost from start date to end of that particular month. If a customer subscribes to a product on May 10 and ends his subscription on June 10th. The cost is billed on monthly basis. So The customer is billed by calculating the cost from May 10th to May 31st. The billing for the rest of the days happens in June cycle and so on

Comment: you should specify that 25 is the amount to pay

Comment: So the problem is that you don't get the correct amount of days when start is 05/10 and end is 06/10?

Comment: I don't get it. If the end date is in another month you want to count until end of the month of the start-date?

Comment: the problem here must be because startday and endday are the same

Comment: @Gabri T - I made the edit and explained what is $25

Comment: Interesting ist that you get 31 when using shockwaves code with start 05/10 and end 06/10 and not 22 like he mentioned. There are a lot easier ways to get the amount of days between two dates btw.

Comment: your `code` works as expected

Comment: @MightyBadaboom - I'm not able to figure out a condition which will calculate the amount from 05/10 to 05/31. Any idea is greatly appreciated

Comment: Then you should edit your question because you highlighted 05/10 till 06/10 as the problem ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yes Tim, you got that right, I want to calculate the amount from 05/10 to 05/31 not until 06/10

Comment: And the expected result with start 05/10 and end 05/31 would be 21?

Comment: your condition`var date2 = finish.Day == 31 && (start.Day == 30 || start.Day == 31) ? 30 : finish.Day;` was wrong you need to change accordingly. it will only works if `finish.date = 31` and `start.data = 30 or 31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i've understood your requirement you only want to calculate the amount for the start-date month. Then following should work which is also simpler and more concise:

```
int startDateDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month);
if (finish.Month != start.Month || finish.Year != start.Year)
    finish = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, startDateDays);
int newDaysDiff = (finish - start).Days + 1;
if (newDaysDiff >= startDateDays)
    newDaysDiff = 30;

float invoiceAmount = (float)(25.0 / 30) * newDaysDiff;
```

With this approach your highlighted row which is a full month will be treated as 22 days.

Answer (score 1):

i ran your code and it actually says its 31 days.
with:

```
var start = new DateTime(2016, 05, 10);     
var finish = new DateTime(2016, 06, 10);
```

http://rextester.com/IKE75462

as mentioned in the comments above, if you are trying to find from 5/10 to 5/31 it´s also right, its 22 days

Comment: Gabri - I don't want to calculate the number of days between start date and end date. I want to calculate the total cost from start date to end of that particular month. If a customer subscribes to a product on May 10 and ends his subscription on June 10th. The cost is billed on monthly basis. So The customer is billed by calculating the cost from May 10th to May 31st. The billing for the rest of the days happens in June cycle and so on.

Comment: ok, i understand it now, please update your question to help us resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int GetDays(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    int newDaysDiff = ((360 * (end.Year - start.Year)) + (30 * ((end.Month - start.Month) == 0 ? 0 : (end.Month - start.Month) - 1)));
    int j = 0;
    if (start.Month == end.Month && start.Year == end.Year) {
        if (start.Day == 1 && end.Day == 31) {
            j = (end.Day - start.Day);
        }
        else {
            j = (end.Day - start.Day) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (start.Day == 1) {
            j = j + 30;
        }
        else {
            j = j + DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month) - start.Day + 1;
        }
        if (end.Day == 30 || end.Day == 31) {
            j = j + 30;
        }
        else {
            j = j + end.Day;
        }
    }
    newDaysDiff = newDaysDiff + j;
    return newDaysDiff;
}
```

Comment: function provide date diff between two date with considering full month as 30 day

Answer (score 0):

You could use this for calculating the total days between two dates

```
var start = new DateTime(2016, 05, 01);
var finish = new DateTime(2016, 05, 31);

var daysBetween = (finish - start).TotalDays + 1;
daysBetween = daysBetween > 30 ? 30 : daysBetween;
```